# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_24 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (77,) When trianing an LSTM network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I was trying to establish a LSTM neural network,the train and test dataset is like below:

```
x_train=np.array(train)
x_train=x_train.reshape(51,77,6)
y_train=list(train.Close[1:])
y_train.append(train.Close[-1])
y_train=np.array(y_train).reshape(51,77)
x_test=np.array(test)
x_test=x_test.reshape(1,77, 6)
y_test=list(test.Close[1:])
y_test.append(test.Close[-1])
y_test=np.array(y_test)
```

and the LSTM network code is

```
BATCH_SIZE = 1
TIME_STEP = 77
FEATURES = 6
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(64,input_shape=(TIME_STEP, FEATURES),return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(32))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", 
          optimizer="adam", 
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

[![][1]][1]
When I tried to use

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train,

      batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,

      nb_epoch=15,

      validation_data=(x_test, y_test))


score, acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=batch_size)
```

to train the model, it returns

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_24 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (77,)

I have tried to change the input training set dimension,but it kept returns error like this one

Comment: the problem is not the input dimension but the target dimension... what's y_train.shape?

Comment: Y_train shape is (51, 77)

Comment: so your last layer must be Dense(77, activation="softmax"). use also categorical_crossentropy instead of binary_crossentropy

Comment: When I changed the Dense layee unit to 77, it raises

Comment: ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_28 to have shape (77,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: model.add(Dense(77, activation="softmax",use_bias= True));model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", 
              optimizer="adam", 
              metrics=['accuracy']); The error still exists